# using the contacts manager in android

Tags: android

i have an app which shows the received messages as a Toast through a BroadcastReceiver. I am presently using the SmsMessage.getOriginatingAddress() method which gives me the number of the sender, how can modify it to get the corresponding name of the sender if stored in the  contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to query the contacts for the rest of the data.

First query for the contacts id using the phone number.

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, address),
    new String[] { Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID }, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null) {
  try {
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      Long id = Long.valueOf(cursor.getLong(0));
      if (Log.DEBUG) Log.v("Found person: " + id);
      return (String.valueOf(id));
    }
  } finally {
    cursor.close();
  }
}
```

Then query for the Contacts name with the id from the first query.

```
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, id),
    new String[] { PeopleColumns.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
  try {
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      String name = cursor.getString(0);
      if (Log.DEBUG) Log.v("Contact Display Name: " + name);
      return name;
    }
  } finally {
    cursor.close();
  }
}
```

You may be able to combine these two queries [somehow.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html)

Comment: when i am using Contacts.Phones then i get a warning that the type is depreciated so which other type should i use?


will the following method give the desired resultL?
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
 resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

Comment: i tried this:  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, address), new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);   but on running the app i get a Null Pointer Exception in this line

Comment: also shouldn't there be a catch statement here?